# Modern Business Intelligence solution

Tags: reporting, powerbi, data-warehouse, azure-data-lake, erp

What is the modern way of building a Business Intelligence solution? I have looked at PowerBI, but I'm wondering what would be the best datasource for it. Is it still traditional datawarehouse solutions that should be used as a datasource? I also hear a lot talk about data lakes, but don't know much about. Or should I just use a regular relational database as the source? Do anyone have any opinions and tips on this?

Comment: If you don't know know much about data lakes... google it. The built in modelling and extraction capabilities of Power BI are impressive but there's always a point where its too complex to be handled that way, and you need to create complex functionality in a database. But it depends on what you're reporting on. Real time reporting doesn't need a database. Things like managing SCD2 do need a database

Answer (score 1):

I think your starting point in your thinking is wrong. You don't chose a front end BI / Dashboard tool and then think what source would be best to connect to it.

You start from your data & information that you want to analyze, report & visualize. Think of structure & variety of data and complexity of analysis, correlations, integrations & business logic.

Then decide how are you going to 
Store the data
Process / Transform the data to correlate, integrate or enrich
report or visualize the data

And its only in step 3 from above high level tasks that you come to start thinking of which Analysis / visualization tool is best fit for such data & its integrations with data storage platform I have as well as nature of the data itself.

That will most likely bring you more success than thinking about it the way you posed that question.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not locked at PowerBI, but it is visual reports like that I want. We are building an ERP system and we would like to provide an Out of the box BI solution to our customers, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: If you are building an ERP system from ground up, you might as well add "out-of-box" reports within the ERP system or develop a connector for things like Microsoft Excel or ODBC to be used by client applications such as PowerBI. 

At the end of the day, your customers should / or would have some built-in reports within your ERP system (think of Operational Reports) and more customized reports / analytical / strategic reports they can build themselves in any given BI tool / environment which "should" be out of scope for your ERP system itself.

Answer (score 1):

Start with your data.

1. Do you have a data warehouse now? If no,
2. Where is your data, databases, Excel, email? Data in databases, like MySQL, is structured. Data in email or other documents is unstructured. Depending on where your data lives impacts how you will analyze it (which is what BI is all about, in the end.) (And a side note, data lakes are best for analyzing structured, semi-structured and unstructured data together. For example if you queried for data in documentation, a SQL DB and older MS Access data dumps.)
3. If you have data in different databases and systems, then I would recommend you start with a data warehouse.  There are many options, one of the easier ones today is using a [cloud-based](https://panoply.io/platform/) solution (AWS, Microsoft, etc.)
4. Once your data is in a location(s) where it can be queried and analyzed as a total data set then you can look at the BI tools that fit your needs.

   4.a. What type of analysis do you need? Queries? Trends? Complex data calculations and transformations?
5. Based on 4.a. look at the tools in the market.  PowerBI is just one of a whole variety of data analysis tools and systems on the market. There are many resources on the web, Google ETL tools.

After all of this you can narrow down your choices and select the solution that works best for you.